# Criação de EVENT no PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Seguinte, tenho um servidor de jogos e estou tentando automatizar a compra de cash no meu site ( o usuario compra cash para gastar no game ).

Eu tenho uma tabela no meu banco chamada USERS:

```
user_id (A.I)
user_name
user_pass
user_email 
dias_vip (definido por padrão = 0 )
```

E tenho uma tabela chamada PEDIDOS:

```
id (A.I)
descricao
status
user_name
```

A tabela USERS é comandada pela minha página de cadastro, OK.

A tabela pedidos só funciona quando a pessoa esta logada no site e compra "cash" para gastar no game. E é ativada junto com o pagseguro. Resumindo, o usuario loga no site e tem um botão de compra de 100 cashs, ele clica nesse botão e então eu gravo o user_name na tabela PEDIDOS e o status = 1 ( q é o padrão do pagseguro para "AGUARDANDO PAGAMENTO" ). Quando a pessoa efetua o pagamento automaticamente eu recebo uma notificação do pagseguro e uma função altera o status para 3 que significa "PAGO".

Vamos a questão em si: gostaria de saber se tem como eu criar um EVENT que adiciona o valor 100 no campo dias_vip da tabela USERS quando o status do pagamento for 3.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, so falta isso para eu finalizar esse processo, obrigado!.

Comment: Você pode colocar um trigger em sua tabela quando o status for 3, o trigger verifica e da update indicando os dias.
http://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-triggers/8088

Comment: Sim, me disseram que da pra fazer, porem eu não entendo da linguagem para fazer isso. consegui fazer os dias_vip diminuir 1 acada dia usando EVENT, mas este não estou conseguindo...